# how to install SQL driver in Tableau on MacOS

Tags: tableau-desktop

Im trying to install sql driver in desktop Tableau on mac

I downloaded the latest jar driver from needed [sql (postgresql)](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/)

As well I installed java jdk (i read that i need it) with `brew install --cask adoptopenjdk`

I tried to run postgres driveer jar but it says 'The PgJDBC driver is not an executable Java program.'

As well official tableau docs dont say anything about it

Answer (score 1):

this downloaded file `postgresql.jar` should be placed in

```
Mac: ~/Library/Tableau/Drivers
```

The same for Win and Linux:

```
Windows: C:\Program Files\Tableau\Drivers
```

```
Linux: /opt/tableau/tableau_driver/jdbc
```